# TYPO3 6.1 TCA and database comparison:

Tags: typo3

In the TYPO3 6.1 Install tool's DB Analyzer, when I run "Compare with TCA", I get huge differences between $TCA and the database.

Though, the suggested values from $TCA seem odd, like old (tiny, improbable types like 'blob' for fe_groups):

[image: Comparison between database and $TCA:]

This goes on and on. I've installed this TYPO3 version from scratch, so it can't be from a prior installation.

What is this? Can I leave it be? If not, where can it be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hole "compare with TCA" will be removed in 6.2. Until then just leave it as it is and ignore it.